# Get other's WhatsApp chat history remotely

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is it possible to transfer the WhatsApp data of someone's phone without having access to their phone? Or alternatively, can I view their chat history remotely?

Comment: I removed the background because it's too private. Without access to their phone, you can't. If their WhatsApp is set to backup the chats, then you *probably* can access it from their Google Drive (but you need to know their account).

Comment: And what **legitimate** reason is here to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without breaking the law. Whats app uses a store and forward mechisnism, that means the messages are stored on the server then forwarded on to the client (i.e the persons phone you are talking to).

The only way to get access to the data on their phone or the whatsapp server is with a court order.

You will be able to see any conversation you have had with them on whatapps, but nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

Find out where they have backed up their data, on the cloud or in their sd cards, then you'll have to retrieve the data and you are good to go.